# code to open form from toolstrip, same code yet among one code cannot do '.show();'

Tags: c#, toolstripmenu

```
    private void userToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frUser user = new frUser();
        user.Show();
    }


    private void categoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frCategory category = new frCategory();
        category.Show();
```

hi, why i can open user form using this code yet cannot do for category?
when i put 'category.' the suggestion didnt show up 'Show' and when i manually do this, the code is not being recognized by vs.

this is a code at a main form to open subform using tool stripbar.

thank you

Comment: _"the code is not being recognized by vs"_ What does that mean? Do you get a compiler error? If so, what does it say? If not, did you try to compile and run the program? What is the type of `frCategory`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your question. There is something missing. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: What is frCategory type gender and ancestor ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Show()` method is part of the [System.Windows.Forms.Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=net-5.0) class.
Your `frCategory` class must inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.